# Elliptic curve addition algorithm for (0,0)

Tags: elliptic-curves

It seems to me that the [Elliptic Curve Addition Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) is undefined for the case $P+P$ if $P=(0,0)$.

Are there any alternative computation methods for this case?

Comment: Is this on a Weierstrass curve $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$?

Comment: yes, sorry for not mentioning this

Comment: Thanks, @anomaly, I think my confusion stemmed from the fact that I overlooked that $\mathcal{O} = (0,0)$

Comment: For a curve in short Weierstrass form, any point $P$ with $y$-coordinate $0$ is a 2-torsion point. So $P+P=\infty$.

Comment: @anomaly I don't understand your comment. To say that the point is at infinity means that it does *not* appear in the affine picture. That's why it's "at infinity."

Comment: @André3000: And this is why I don't post before breakfast.

Comment: The point at $\infty$ is $(\infty,\infty)$ not $(0,0)$. To find $P+P$ we need the tangent at $P$ that is the line $(x_P+ct,y_P+dt)$ ($(c,d) \ne (0,0)$) such that $f'(0) = 0$ where $f(t) = (y_P+dt)^2-(x_P+ct)^3-a(x_P+ct)^2-b(x_P+ct)$ then as usual we pick the 3rd root of $f(t)=-c^3 t^2(t-T), T = 1+f(1)/c^3$ then $P+P = (x_P+cT,-y_P-dT)$. Here with $P = (0,0)$ the tangent line is $c=0,d=1$ and $T=\infty$,$P+P = (\infty,\infty)$ ($c^3T$ is non-zero that's why $cT = \infty$ even if $c=0$ .... hard to justify without rational functions on the curve or projective curves stuffs)